# Can you explain how it works?

Tags: java, math, stringbuilder

It would be awesome if someone could give me a proper explanation of the code :)

Code is working and I like it, however as I am learning Java, need to understand every bit of it.

Thanks!

Checked `StringBuilder()` - seems fine,
However part inside the `loop` is not quite clear.

```java
    public class SquareDigit {

        public int squareDigits(int n) {
               StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

               while(n > 0) {
                   int digit = n % 10;

                   int square = digit * digit;
                   builder.insert(0, square);

                   n = Math.floorDiv(n, 10);
               }

               return Integer.valueOf(builder.toString());
         }

     }
```

Comment: There are many things going on in the loop. What specifically is not clear to you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
To be honest, whole calculation process is a bit of mistery in this one.
Would be amazing to receive a list of processes going on, when code gets executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
while(n > 0) {
```

While the `int n` is bigger than 0 do the following.

```java
int digit = n % 10;
```

A new `int digit` is initialized as n MODULO 10. Modulo returns the remainder of the division n / 10. So for example if n is 21, it will return 1.

```java
int square = digit * digit;
builder.insert(0, square);
```

A new `int square` is initialised as the product of `digit` times itself. The method `insert()` from class `StringBuilder` is called with 0 and `square` as parameters. 0 is the offset and `square` is the char value to be inserted.

```java
n = Math.floorDiv(n, 10);
```

`Math.floorDiv()` returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) integer value that is less than or equal to the algebraic quotient. For example `Math.floorDiv(25, 5)` will return `5`.

```java
return Integer.valueOf(builder.toString());
```

Finally, you return the value you built before. `builder.toString()` returns the `StringBuilder` object as a String. `Integer.valueOf(String str)` is used to return an `Integer` object holding the value of the specified `String str`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take `n=25`.
  After passing the value to `squareDigits(int 25)`.

1)First it creates a `StringBuilder`.

2)`while(n > 0)`:  25 > 0 is true, so it satisfies the condition to get into the loop.

3)`int digit = n % 10`:  n = 5.

4)`int square = digit * digit`: square = 25.

5)`builder.insert(0,square)`: It inserts `square` value at the 0th position into the `builder`.

6)`n = Math.floorDiv(n, 10);`:
   `Math.floorDiv(int x,int y)`  returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) integer value that is less than or equal to the algebraic quotient. n = 2.

7) Repeats Step 2 with value 2. `digit` becomes 2, `square` becomes 4, `builder` inserts the value 4, but 25 is already present, so the latest value 4 is appended to 25.

8) `n` becomes `Math.floorDiv(2, 10)` which returns 0.2. While checking `while` condition it doesn't satisfy the equation.

9) `builder` is converted to a String using `toString()` and by using `Integer.parseInt()`, It converts the returned String value to Integer which finally returns 425.